# Accessing files properly within docker container

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to access a csv file in my project. The file is not located in the same place relative to the working directory. When running my app in a docker container the file system remains the same, however accessing the files becomes different.

These files are hosted locally on the container itself, it is not on a volume.

I have a python project running in a docker container. Accessing the files looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/app/test-files/'+filename)
```

However when I run it locally with 'py main.py' I can access the files using this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/test-files/'+filename)
```

Is there a way to make it so I can access the files on both local and container filesystems using the same pathing syntax?

Comment: Docker is intentionally designed so that programs running in containers can't easily access host files.  Can you run this program outside Docker, perhaps in a Python virtual environment?  Or in your program can you make the data-file location configurable with an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

While building the image create the directory under "/" and copy the file to "/test-files/" directory.  Post that you can run the python file as per your requirement

```
df = pd.read_csv('/test-files/'+filename)
```